# Считывание строки по три элемента python в цикле

Tags: python

Есть строка, например:

```py
rna = CCGUCUAAGGGGGAUCUGGGCGGGCGUGGUACCAGUCCGUACGGGGAGGAGUAGCGACCCGUGUCGGGUCUCC
```

С помощью цикла `for` нужно брать по тройке букв из строки и проверять их далее

```
for i in rna[:3:]:
    print(i)
```

делая по инструкции в интернете не получается, функцией split также не получилось
должно быть по типу: `i = CCG`, `i = UCU` и т.д.

Comment: https://ideone.com/NFZ8Bb

Comment: Не может быть такой инструкции.

Comment: отличное решение. огромное спасибо. "code = rna[code_pos: code_pos + 3]" - не знал что так можно в цикле, очень даже странно

Answer (score 4):

Первый вариант:

```
str = 'helloworld'
list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)] * 3)))
```

P.S. Если строка не будет делиться ровно на три части, то последняя часть (с одной или двумя буквами) будет удаляться. Чтобы её не удалять, можно написать так:

```
import itertools
list(map(''.join, itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(str)] * 3, fillvalue='')))
```

Второй вариант:

```
import textwrap
str = 'helloworld'
textwrap.wrap(str, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Как насчёт такого?

```
rna = 'SomeText'
i = 0
while i <= len(rna) - 2:
    print(rna[i:i+3])
    i += 3
```

Возможно есть более элегантные решения, но это быстро доступно и понятно =)

Answer (score 1):

С циклом можно вот так коротко сделать, ведь у `range` есть третий необязательный параметр `шаг`:

```
for i in range(0, len(rna), 3):
    print(rna[i:i+3])
```